# how to update a record based on updated_at age without callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of records in Rails, and these records have a boolean field to make them public or private. I need a way of changing every public record to private **whenever** updated_at >= 30 days ago.

I don't know where to start. Any advice, links and tips are welcome. Thank you!

**The Solution**

Following the recommendation from @lol007 i use whenever gem. The steps i follow are:

1. Create a app with a table Post title:string content:text status:boolean and run first time the server to add info, then stop the server and continue with the other steps.
2. Add whenever gem to my gemfile and run bundle install.
3. Run wheneverize . in the console to create the config/schedule.rb file
4. Add in the models/post.rb the next code:

   ```
   def self.check_updated_at
     where('updated_at < ?', 30.minutes.ago).update_all({ :status => :true })
   end
   ```
5. Add in config/schedule.rb the next code:

   ```
   every 3.minutes do
     runner "Post.check_updated_at"
   end
   ```
6. Because im working in development, i run the next command:

   ```
   $ whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'
   ```
7. Then to check my cron is working i run the next command:

   ```
   $ crontab -l
   ```
8. My last step is run the rails server and put to work my app.

Other lines i used in my test are:

```
    $ whenever -w
```

To generate the cron file in production. And

```
   $ crontab -r
```

To remove the cron file, when is not the one i want.

thank you all for your time and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Whenever Gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). For example, in config/schedule.rb:

```
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "YourModel.check_updated_at"
end
```

In your model:

```
def self.check_updated_at
  where('updated_at > ?', 30.days.ago).update_all({private: true})
end
```

Comment: thanks for your comments, i haved this issue stopped because the client dont needed more, but right now again i want to add to a new project. Whenever Gem works with ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.2.11? Becuase thats my configuration right now.

Comment: I think, yes. "Compatible with Ruby 1.8.7-1.9.3, JRuby, and Rubinius." (c)

Comment: i try with whenever gem, but i dont see something happen. Look my example: https://gist.github.com/stanmx/7310350

Comment: I continue try to run whenever in my RVM environment, but i try with command "echo 'something.'" and don't work. Its something i need to have before run whenever gem in my app?

Comment: Right now im received a mail message: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: posts: UPDATE "posts" SET "status" = 'false' WHERE (created_at < '2013-11-05 17:51:01.873901').

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a database field that updates itself based on time, you could add a new method to your model:

```
class Wtf< ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  # like this
  def is_public
    updated_at> 30.days.ago
  end

  # or like this
  def self.only_public
    where("updated_at> ?", 30.days.ago)
  end
end
```

Then use it like:

```
Wtf.only_public.joins(:somethingelse).where("somethingelses.attribute= 42")
```

or

```
Wtf.first.is_public
```

Comment: `where("updated_at> ?", 30.days_ago)` - just a typo in single quote

Comment: your `is_public` method will always return false.

Comment: Also, u can only use `updated_at> 30.days.ago` in `is_public` method to return `true` or `false` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 YourModel.update_all({:private => true}, "updated_at > 30.days.ago")
```